# Redirect all requests using Express 3?

Tags: node.js, express, node.js-connect

What is the best way to do this?

I'd like to redirect all requests from `www.example.com` to `example.com`

`*.example.com` to `example.com` would be ideal

I would think some type of middleware. I still hate this, because it seems so inelegant and slightly wasteful, but I think my only option is to do this server-side.

Comment: You can fix this in your server config. What are you running Node on? Nginx? Apache?

Comment: @leemachin like the tags say, I'm using Express(which uses Connect)

Comment: Well then the source of your inelegance is not putting it behind a proxy (like Nginx or Apache).

Comment: I have no need of a proxy. Besides, a proxy would do the same thing and is just as inelegant. The inelegance is something I have to deal with, I just need to know how to go a global redirect in these. I'm not looking to debate with you on using a proxy or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since Express 3 doesn't use its own HTTP server (instead you pass your app to `http.createServer`), it doesn't know what port it's running on unless you tell it. That said, you can do basically what you want to do with the following:

```
app.use(function(request, response, next) {
  var newHost = request.host.replace(/^www\./, '');
  if (request.host != newHost) {
    // 301 is a "Moved Permanently" redirect.
    response.redirect(301, request.protocol + "://" + newHost + request.url);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

You could export this in a module and wrap it in a generator that takes a port:

```
// no_www.js

module.exports = function(port) {
  app.use(function(request, response, next) {
    var newHost = request.host.replace(/^www\./, '');
    if (request.host != newHost) {
      var portStr = '';
      if (request.protocol == 'http' && port != 80) portStr = ':' + port;
      if (request.protocol == 'https' && port != 443) portSt r= ':' + port;
      // 301 is a "Moved Permanently" redirect.
      response.redirect(301, request.protocol + "://" + newHost + portStr + request.url);
    } else {
      next();
    }
  });
}

// app.js

var noWww = require('./no_www');
var app = express();

app.configure("development", function() {
  app.set("port", 3000);
});

...

app.use(noWww(app.get('port')));
```

Comment: That's awesome. That's just what I needed. .use() isn't in the Express documentation so I wasn't exactly sure what it did. I'm assuming it's a wrapper for functions that execute on each request?

Comment: That's unfortunate, it seems documentation for `use` got lost when the new site went up for version 3. You are right, `use` exposes Connect's (Express is built on Connect) middleware system, so that no-www module I wrote above is middleware for Connect/Express. Check out http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/ for more information.

Comment: This held the answer to my search for Express 4. The only piece I needed was response.redirect(statusCode, destination); Unfortunately it behaved in a pretty strange way. I gave it a complete url and instead of redirecting to the url, the url got appended to the end of the current path. I solved that by just redirecting to "/" which was my desired destination in this case, but if I ever have to redirect to another domain, I'll have to figure out what I did wrong.